# Spring MVC Table

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to display data in tables in Spring MVC , I have pasted the JSP code and the controller code below, when I hit the url /test/grid I can see it hits the Employee.jsp page but nothing gets loaded. The chrome console does not show any error also the getActiveTeamData method is never called.

JSP Code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee</title>
<body>
 <c:if test="${!empty employees}">  
 <table align="center" border="1">  
  <tr>  
   <th>Name</th>  
   <th>Position</th>  
   <th>Salary</th>
   <th>Office</th>
   <th>Start Date</th>  
  </tr>  

  <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="category">  
   <tr>  
    <td><c:out value="${employee.name}"/></td>  
    <td><c:out value="${employee.position}"/></td>  
    <td><c:out value="${employee.salary}"/></td> 
     <td><c:out value="${employee.office}"/></td>  
     <td><c:out value="${employee.start_Date}"/></td>    
   </tr>  
  </c:forEach>  
 </table> 
 </c:if>  
</body>
</html>
```

Java Code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class EmployeeController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/grid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tableServiceCall() {

        logger.info("Log4j info is working");
        logger.warn("Log4j warn is working");
        logger.debug("Log4j debug is working");
        logger.error("Log4j error is working");
        System.out.println("System out is working");
        return "Employee";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<EmployeeDTO> getActiveTeamData(@PathVariable String name) {

        List<EmployeeDTO> listEmployees = new ArrayList<EmployeeDTO>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            EmployeeDTO employeeDTO1 = new EmployeeDTO();

            employeeDTO1.setName("Java Honk");
            employeeDTO1.setPosition("Architect");
            employeeDTO1.setSalary("$000,800");
            employeeDTO1.setOffice("NY");
            employeeDTO1.setStart_Date("05/05/2010");



            EmployeeDTO employeeDTO2 = new EmployeeDTO();

            employeeDTO2.setName("Igor Vornovitsky");
            employeeDTO2.setPosition("Sr. Architect");
            employeeDTO2.setSalary("$400,800");
            employeeDTO2.setOffice("NY");
            employeeDTO2.setStart_Date("05/05/2011");



            EmployeeDTO employeeDTO3 = new EmployeeDTO();

            employeeDTO3.setName("Ramesh Arrepu");
            employeeDTO3.setPosition("Architect");
            employeeDTO3.setSalary("$300,400");
            employeeDTO3.setOffice("NY");
            employeeDTO3.setStart_Date("05/05/2009");

            listEmployees.add(employeeDTO1);
            listEmployees.add(employeeDTO2);
            listEmployees.add(employeeDTO3);

        }

        return listEmployees;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String testApp() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
```

Comment: When open the URL /test/grid then your handler method `tableServiceCall` gets called. Which doesn't provide any model data to the view "Employee" and therefore no table gets rendered.The URL for `getActiveTeamData` would be /test/employees, but this handler method doesn't render a JSP view because it has a `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

`tableServiceCall` doesnt populate the model expected by JSP view so nothing is shown.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/grid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String tableServiceCall(Model model) {

    List<EmployeeDTO> listEmployees = ...
    // populate employee list
    model.addAttribute("category", listEmployees);

    return "Employee";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your method `tableServiceCall` you need to add the `List<EmployeeDTO>` and popolate and send it with `ModelAndView` try something like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/grid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String tableServiceCall() {

   List<EmployeeDTO> listEmployees = new ArrayList<EmployeeDTO>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        EmployeeDTO employeeDTO1 = new EmployeeDTO();

        employeeDTO1.setName("Java Honk");
        employeeDTO1.setPosition("Architect");
        employeeDTO1.setSalary("$000,800");
        employeeDTO1.setOffice("NY");
        employeeDTO1.setStart_Date("05/05/2010");



        EmployeeDTO employeeDTO2 = new EmployeeDTO();

        employeeDTO2.setName("Igor Vornovitsky");
        employeeDTO2.setPosition("Sr. Architect");
        employeeDTO2.setSalary("$400,800");
        employeeDTO2.setOffice("NY");
        employeeDTO2.setStart_Date("05/05/2011");



        EmployeeDTO employeeDTO3 = new EmployeeDTO();

        employeeDTO3.setName("Ramesh Arrepu");
        employeeDTO3.setPosition("Architect");
        employeeDTO3.setSalary("$300,400");
        employeeDTO3.setOffice("NY");
        employeeDTO3.setStart_Date("05/05/2009");

        listEmployees.add(employeeDTO1);
        listEmployees.add(employeeDTO2);
        listEmployees.add(employeeDTO3);

    }

     return new ModelAndView("Employee", "employees", listEmployees);
   }
```

And try to use `not empty` instead of `!empty` in your jsp page like this:

```
   <c:if test="${not empty employees}">
```